# How to Subtract number of days from current date in HQL query

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I am using HQL to get the data inserted exact 21 days from now. Here is my Code

```
Query queryThreeWeek = session.createQuery("from Users where createdDate = CURDATE()-21");
List<Users> userDetailsThreeWeekList = queryThreeWeek.list();
```

I can not use `createSQLQuery`.
Right now I am not getting any data, but there is data for the date `2016-06-20`. And that is because of the month changed because when I used `CURDATE()-7` I got the correct data of the date `2016-07-04`.
The calculation for dat is like;

```
2016-07-11 - 7 = 20160704
2016-07-11 - 21 = 20160690
```

I also Tired using `INTERVAL` which is for `native sqlQuery`. Here is my code for using `INTERVAL` in HQL:

```
Query queryThreeWeek = session.createQuery("from Users where createdDate = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 21 DAY ) )");
List<Users> userDetailsThreeWeekList = queryThreeWeek.list();
```

Also tried

```
Query queryThreeWeek = session.createQuery("from Users where createdDate = DATE( DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 21 DAY ) )"); 
List<Users> userDetailsThreeWeekList = queryThreeWeek.list();
```

but it is giving me exception like: `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 21`.

So what can I use instead of subtracting the day like this: `CURDATE()-21`? in HQL only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using one native SQL query which can get me the exact date.

```
Query sub3Week = session.createSQLQuery("select DATE( DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 21 DAY ) ) from dual");
List<Date> sub3WeekList = sub3Week.list();
```

And then I use this data in the HQL query like this:

```
Query queryThreeWeek = session.createQuery("from Users where createdDate = :createdDate");
queryThreeWeek.setParameter("createdDate", sub3WeekList.get(0).toString());
List<Users> userDetailsThreeWeekList = queryThreeWeek.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

The **solution with HQL** is quite simple:

```
        final long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - java.time.Duration.ofDays(21).toMillis();
        final javax.persistence.Query query = entityManagerOrSession.createQuery(
                "SELECT x FROM users x WHERE x.createddate> :time");
        query.setParameter("time", new java.sql.Timestamp(time));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use date_Sub in a **native SQL** query (not a HQL query!):

```
 "from Users where createdDate =   DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 21 DAY ) )"
```

Comment: I am getting unexpected token: 21

Comment: i have test in mysql this way and seems correct 

    select DATE( DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 21 DAY ) ) from dual;

Comment: But this is not  the way I am doing it, what I am getting is: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 21

Comment: update your question and show the exact code you are using ..please

Comment: I replaced the query with your suggestion, and then only I am getting this exception

Comment: please show me the exact code you are using  .. form Query  queryThree  ... until ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117006/discussion-between-shivam-and-scaisedge).

Comment: The only alternative is use  of native  sqlQuery .. seems that hybernate don't suport date_sub ..

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `+` and `-` operations with dats in hiebrnate. I was able to get it by using the below conditions.

**Timestamp:**    `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+4640000`

Date:    `CURRENT_DATE+1`